# Android Google Maps Not Working After APK Release

Tags: android, google-maps

I have Android app which include Google Maps It was working fine before releasing the app, but after releasing the maps are not shown.
Although I've added SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from Google console after releasing and added it to the restricted apps

[image: SHA-1 after releasing]

[image: API Key Restrictions]

So the 2 SHA-1 are included with the package name, the Maps works fine when running the app directly from android studio, but it shows nothing when downloading the app from playstore, any Ideas ?

Comment: Any help, I've tried alot but the issue still the same ?

Comment: Also I've removed the restriction for api using, but still not working when installed from playstore.....

Comment: same here. any update?

Answer (score 14):

It's because Google Play is signing app with different SHA-1 Fingerprint, so you need to take it and register in google developer's console

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem. Please make sure you have set your **release api key** on your app resources.

In your app you might have:

> src/**debug**/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

where you set your debug key and also:

> src/**release**/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

where you must set your release key. If you have created only one API Key with both SHA-1, then you must introduce the same as in debug.

One more thing, in the Google Developers Console besides the **debug SHA-1** and the **Google Play Console SHA-1** I also add the **release SHA-1** of the keystore I've use to sign my app.