# Google Map not showing in real devices

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I have a problem with a google map, it works only on the simulatore but not on real devices.

Here's my google_map_api.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIza...</string
```

and my manifest:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIza..." />
```

and my class:

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

    final SupportMapFragment map =  (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map.getMapAsync(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this.getActivity(), R.raw.mapstyle));

    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {

    }

         return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: On what devices have you tested this code? Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807764/android-google-maps-not-working-after-apk-release/51034219#51034219 see my answer in that post

Answer (score 0):

please print your logs but before that please check that you are online

Answer (score 0):

Your google_maps_key has to be registered with the release certificate (SHA-1) that you use to generate the apk that you install in the devices

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Google Maps API key and check whether the internet is working or not in the real device, and device minSdkVersion is 21 and upper.